# Anti-Iron property of material

Tags: ferromagnetism

Hello I've been seeing it on the YouTube, but there is not a single information on how it happens.

Those who have uploaded the videos call it "anti-iron". Appearntly it's a property of the material in which it moderately repels iron. In some of the videos the creators treated some metal coins with a chemical and it starts to repel needle suspended from a thread. It looks very suspicious about how it works, please clear my doubts about how it works or if it's a scam.

Links to some of the videos on YouTube:
https://youtu.be/MkuxA8-bvgU
https://youtu.be/sylU6YxZO1c

Note: Please don't downvote the question, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: If you want to create a stable magnetization, you should first avoid something like a flame from a lighter (first video).

Answer (score 0):

If the video makers are asking for money for their mysterious "anti-iron chemical" then its a scam. I only watched one video, but there are various times in that video when the coin and the needle are out of sight and could have been swapped for magnetised copies.